# What should i do to create Custom code validator according to my sdk in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vssdk

I have never developed visual studio extensions. I don't know what should I do create custom validator that will validate code written in c# using my dll, whether they confirm to certain criteria.

For example, I have a class like this:

```
public class ReturnMessage<T> where T : new()
{
    public void SetSuccess(string message, T value)
    {}
}
```

I would like to check if this class is being used to return response, then `SetSuccess` method should be called before return is sent.

Any directions, for starters would of great help as I don't what should be ideally done to achieve this.